# Nth root with simple operators

Tags: c#, libraries

I am trying to create a function to find the nth root of a number without using libraries like Math etc. I can only use the +-*/ operators.

So far I have been trying to recreate the `Math.Pow(double num, double root)` function but with no luck as I cannot come up with a solution that takes two doubles.

I have tried using this:

```
double pow(double a, int n) {
double result = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result *= a
}
return result;
```

But this does not really work for me because it takes an int for the root instead of a double.

I need the source code or a recreation of `Math.Pow(double a, double b)`

Comment: What do yo mean by *I cannot come up with a solution that takes two doubles*? do you have any errors/exceptions? post the code and explain what exactly is the problem.

Comment: @Guy I think the OP managed to calculate x^y when x is a double and y an integer but not when y is a double too (including 0.5 for sqrt)

Comment: @vc74 right on the money

Comment: @vc74 if you could give me code examples that would be great

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem, it's a maths problem.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root (Wikipedia) for an explanation of the Nth Root algorithm, and https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Nth_root (Rosetta Code) for code samples. As to the comment stating that the code uses library functions: the only library functions used in the C# sample on Rosetta Code are ``Abs()`` and ``Pow()``, the latter for positive integer values only; you should be able to write these functions (or find code examples) yourself.

Comment: What examples or directions did the teacher give you?

Comment: @bommelding the example I was given was Math.Pow(number, 1.0/root) and I was told to make it without using the Math library and with using only simple operators

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's adapt code from Rosetta Code (https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Nth_root):

```
private static double DPow(double a, int n)
{
    var result = 1.0;
    for (; n > 0; n--) result *= a;
    return result;
}

private static double DAbs(double a)
{
    return (a > 0.0) ? a : -a;
}

public static double NthRoot(double a, int n, double p)
{
    var _n = (double)n;
    var x0 = a;
    var x1 = a / _n;
    while (DAbs(x0 - x1) > p)
    {
        x1 = x0;
        x0 = (1.0 / _n) * (((_n - 1.0) * x1) + (a / DPow(x1, _n - 1.0)));
    }
    return x0;
}

public static double NthRoot(double a, int n)
{
    return NthRoot(a, n, .0001);
}
```

We implement a simple pow function, and a very simple abs function, and use both to implement the algorithm given by the Rosetta Code site. Hope this fulfils your requirements!

Comment: It took me 1 minute to find this… @PinkBoi please learn how to research.

Comment: This is a good comment but a very poor answer. Link only answers are considered very low quality in Stackoverflow. You should know that by now.

Comment: @dumetrulo the link you posted is using Math libraries.. please learn to read

Comment: To the downvoters after my edit: please explain yourselves so I can try and improve my answer; otherwise I will have to conclude that my attempt to help is not appreciated, and delete my answer…

Comment: @bommelding I answer questions for the fun of it. Receiving downvotes with no explanation is no fun. Whether getting a free solution to his homework is useful to the OP is not my concern (although I agree that they are not likely to learn from it the same as if they had investigated themselves, and my originally downvoted no-code answer was actually more conductive to such an experience).

Comment: @dumetrulo your answer was correct just on DPow you should return result instead of a. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I edited the answer to return the correct value.